# Meteor prefetch data

Tags: meteor

On Meteor, I'd like to prefetch data. I know this is normally automatically done. But there is a small wait for some action.

For example, I put a jquery event and change a session variable. Minimongo don't have that datas and have to fetch them.

I'd like to make an animation during which I'm fetching data and at the end of the animation change the templates.

Is it possible? How mould you do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only way minimongo won't have your data is when your subscription changes. So you could do

Edit: Clearing it up

```
Meteor.autosubscribe(function() {
  //ADD LOADING TO PAGE HERE (1)
  page = Session.get('paging')
  Session.set('Sess1', true)
  Meteor.subscribe('testdata', page, function() {
    //remove loading to page here (2)
    Session.set('Sess1', false)
  });
});
```

For the template it doesn't need to change. You could set a Session at (1) and set another at (2).

So

```
<template name="test">
  {{#if Sess1}}
    might be loading here
  {{else}}
    display the data here
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure to understand well. If I use autosubscribe without adding anything: no authentification. If I have a database with, let's say 100000 items, meteor charge all the elements locally?

Comment: @Farf Feel free to add a reactive variable inside Meteor.autosubscribe as you need.It might be this, "I put a jquery event and change a session variable.", Session variable. So when the function gets called again the loading will start and when the subscription is done. The template will display the data.